# CakePHP Entity Name vs Table Name Not Pluralizing

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to figure out how to get CakePHP to recognize the plural/singular form of faqs/faq for my table name and model.

I have tried adding an Inflector rule, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
Inflector::rules('plural', ['faq' => 'faqs']);
```

It keeps telling me that is is looking for `dbname.faq`, when it should be looking for `dbname.faqs`

Thank you for your help.

Added code:

\Model\Entity\Faq.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

/**
 * Faq Entity
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $question
 * @property string $answer
 * @property string $category
 * @property \Cake\I18n\FrozenTime $created
 */
//this should be "Faq" but its not workign for some reason
class Faq extends Entity
{

    /**
     * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
     *
     * Note that when '*' is set to true, this allows all unspecified fields to
     * be mass assigned. For security purposes, it is advised to set '*' to false
     * (or remove it), and explicitly make individual fields accessible as needed.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_accessible = [
        'question' => true,
        'answer' => true,
        'category' => true,
        'created' => false
    ];
}
```

\Model\Table\FaqsTable.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

/**
 * Faqs Model
 *
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Faq get($primaryKey, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Faq newEntity($data = null, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Faq[] newEntities(array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Faq|bool save(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Faq patchEntity(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Faq[] patchEntities($entities, array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\Faq findOrCreate($search, callable $callback = null, $options = [])
 *
 * @mixin \Cake\ORM\Behavior\TimestampBehavior
 */
class FaqsTable extends Table
{

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('faqs');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    }

    /**
     * Default validation rules.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
     * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->integer('id')
            ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

        $validator
            ->scalar('question')
            ->maxLength('question', 500)
            ->allowEmpty('question');

        $validator
            ->scalar('answer')
            ->maxLength('answer', 1000)
            ->allowEmpty('answer');

        $validator
            ->scalar('category')
            ->maxLength('category', 50)
            ->allowEmpty('category');

        return $validator;
    }
}
```

HelpController.php:

```
<?php

// src/Controller/HelpController.php

namespace App\Controller;

class HelpController extends AppController 
{
    public function index()
    {
    }

    public function faq()
    {
        $this->loadModel('Faq');
        $faqs = $this->Faq->find();
        $this->set(compact('faq'));
    }
}
```

Error:

`SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dbname.faq' doesn't exist Cake\Database\Exception`

Comment: did you bake your app from a faqs database table? what is you table model named (file)?

Comment: Table model is FaqsTable.php.  Entity model is Faq.php @AlexStallen  And yes, I did a bake.

Comment: thats weird, I just checked an old project of mine where I also have a faqstable and I dont see any things I changed to get it to work.

Comment: I first created the table in the database.  Then I ran the bake.

Comment: What is the structure of the table in the database?

Comment: columns: id (int, pk), question (string), answer (string), category (string), created (timestamp)

Comment: Check the table name that is set in your table class's `initialize()` call (that's relevant code that should ideally have been in your question, along with the code that actually causes the error to be triggered), and delete your model cache (`tmp/cache/models`).